# A question about Set definition, a logical doubt

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Set definition :In mathematics, a set is a well-defined collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right.

Suppose $A=\left\{\frac{1}{x-1}|x\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$
Now with respect to definition : $A$ is a set  ? (specially Well-defined ,distinct objects )
I apologize If my question Is not clear ,but I am in doubt with definition in $x=1$

What Should I say for $x=1$ ? or $A$

Answer (score 2):

If $f: A \to B$ is a function, then $\{ f(a) \mid a \in A\}$ is indeed a set.

However, the function you describe is not a function with domain all of $\mathbb{Z}$, so you need to instead take 
$$\left\{ \frac{1}{x-1} \;\middle|\; x\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{1\}\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x=1$, $1\over 1-x$ is undefined.

The expression $A = \left\{{1\over 1-x}, x\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ is a definition of $A$. But since it contains an undefined element, $A$ is undefined too.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a set, a certain amount of latitude might be OK, but you can always make things more precise.

My guess is that

$A=\{ q \in \mathbb{Q}  \,   \text{ | there exist a } n \in \mathbb{Z} \text{, } \;n \ne 1                   \text { and } q = \frac{1}{1-n} \}$

Answer (score 1):

Putting it another way, are you asking what is this (one-element) set $\{\frac{1}{0}\}$? But why do you focus on a higher-level entity (the set of some elements) before focusing on the elements themselves: in this case $\frac{1}{0}$? If you define elements you can proceed with using them (among other things, building sets containing them), otherwise you can't do anything with something not defined, not even building sets containing them.

---

> **Edit:**
>
> I must change my mind about what already expressed.
>
> But in any case the question does not deal with a "logical doubt" but how to interpret the shorthand notation you used.
>
> As reported in *Algebra: Chapter $\textit{0}$* by Paolo Aluffi, what you wrote is a commonly adopted shorthand notation that must be interpreted in this way:
>
> $$A=\{y\vert ~\exists x \in\mathbb{Z}\text{ such that }y=1/(x-1)\}$$
>
> that is, the existential quantifier is understood.